# Why does list index go out of range when using random module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am building a Chatbot and I was able to make it answer to me randomly. I added all the responses in a list and whenever I greet it, It shoots me a random answer. Now this is fine, but sometimes, the program throws an exception - `IndexError: list index out of range`. I don't understand why the list index is going out of range. The list has 6 items, and by using `random.randint(0,len(slist))` I was able to get a random response.

I have used exception handling to fix this problem. But, I want to know why it gives an error.

Here's the code without exception handling:

```
if self.Has_user_greeted == False:
    self.AI_Greet()
 else:
    # goes out of range here
    self.AI_respond = random.randint(0,len(self.AI_Greeted))
    print(self.AI_Greeted[self.AI_respond])
```

Answer (score 2):

`randint` does not act like the rest of Python (for historical reasons relating to other computer languages). In particular, `randint()` *does* include the upper bound, unlike Python's list indices and `len()`.

So use `randint(0,len(self.AI_Greeted) - 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because list indexes start at `0` and `randint` will choose a number in the range you specify `inclusively` with the upper bound. Observe this example:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> len(a)
3
```

So, now try to get the value at index `3`:

```
>>> a[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Because the highest index is actually `2`.

What you want to do in your example is simply `-1` the length:

```
random.randint(0,len(self.AI_Greeted) - 1)
```